# Define compound classes by intersection of two raster images in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, intersection

I am trying to create ecoregions by the intersections of soil classes and land cover classification.

Ideally I would like to have something like "forest_Entisol" and "forest_Oxisol" or as well "grass_Oxisol".

I have attempted to multiply the two classified images like this:

```js
//import study area
var area = ee.FeatureCollection('users/jonathanreith/KK')
Map.centerObject(area,9);
//////////////////////////////SPATIAL JOIN//////////////////////////////////
var soil      = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_GRTGROUP_USDA-SOILTAX_C/v01");
var globc     = ee.Image("ESA/GLOBCOVER_L4_200901_200912_V2_3");
var ecounit = soil.add(globc);
var ecounit = ee.Image.cat([soil, globc]);
var ecounit = ecounit.select(
    ['grtgroup', 'landcover', 'qa'], // old names
    ['soil', 'landcover', 'trash']  // new names
);
var ecounit = ecounit.select('soil').multiply(ecounit.select('landcover')).rename('ecounit');
print(ecounit);
```

It kind of works, but I have no idea what is behind each value. Furthermore, classes are potentially not unique, because the product of the two values could have the same number as a original class.

Is there a better way in GEE to intersect two raster images?

I already saw [Intersect of raster image on Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308136/intersect-of-raster-image-on-google-earth-engine)

Comment: Can you provide two lists in your answer: One with the names of soil image and one list with it's corresponding values? They should be retrievable via de OpenLandMap site. Those of the globc are already provided in the metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could multiply one of the layers by a large scalar and then add the other, which will result in unique combinations. For instance, suppose land cover values range from *1-100* and you multiply the image by *1,000*, the new range will be *1,000-100,000*. This works if the values of the soil layer are less than *1000*.

In this example, up to the one thousands place is reserved for soil classes and one thousands up to the one millions place is land cover classes. For instance, suppose clay equals *10* and conifer forest cover equals *80* the resulting class would be *(0)80,010*.

The code would look something like:

```js
var landcover = ecounit.select('landcover').multiply(1000);
var soil = ecounit.select('soil');

var soilLcCombo = landcover.add(soil);
```

Here is a working example:

```js
var nlcd = ee.Image('USGS/NLCD/NLCD2011');

var landCover = nlcd.select('landcover');
var treeCover = nlcd.select('percent_tree_cover');

var landCoverScaled = landCover.select('landcover').multiply(1000);
var lcTcCombo = landCoverScaled.add(treeCover);

Map.addLayer(landCover, {min: 0, max: 100}, 'Land cover');
Map.addLayer(treeCover, {min: 0, max: 100}, 'Tree cover');
Map.addLayer(lcTcCombo, {min: 0, max: 1e5}, 'Land cover & tree cover');
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d71c0d1e1eae6351966867071fc1836b?as_external)

Use the Inspector - click a location and note the value of the "Land cover" layer, the "Tree cover" layer and the "Land cover & tree cover" layer. The "Land cover & tree cover" value contains the classes of the other two, where up to the one thousands place is reserved for tree cover classes and one thousands up to the one millions place is for land cover classes.

[image]

Comment: The problem of ambiguous classes still remains with this answer. E.g. land cover class of 1000 and soil of 2 will result in a new class of 2000, while land cover of 2000 and soil class of 1 will create the same class 2000

Comment: You have not understood my answer. Do not multiply the layers; ADD them after one has been scaled by a large number. I have edited my answer to include a working example to help clarify.